# Accessing length of nested property

Tags: javascript, nested

I have this data and would like to access the length (i.e. number) of procedures nested within 'procedures'. How might I do this?

```
let specialties = [
  {
    name: 'Emergency)',
    number: '1',
    procedures: {
      procedure1: 'PoPo',
      procedure2: 'Lala',
      procedure3: 'Dipsy',
    }]
```

Comment: `Object.keys(specialities[0].procedures).length`

Answer (score 0):

You can count the keys of the object:

```js
let specialties = [
  {
    name: 'Emergency)',
    number: '1',
    procedures: {
      procedure1: 'PoPo',
      procedure2: 'Lala',
      procedure3: 'Dipsy',
    }
  }
]

console.log(Object.keys(specialties[0].procedures).length)
```